# How to add XML serialization instructions without modifying the class

Tags: c#, vb.net, xml-serialization

Is there a clever way of adding XML serialization instructions without modifying the serialized class?

I don’t like the default serialization and I can’t modify the class. I was considering inheriting the class, and using Shadows (VB.NET) to re-implement the properties (with the serialization instructions), but it results in a lot of duplicate code and just looks terrible.

The ideal solution I'm looking for is basically a method to keep all the serialization instructions in a separate file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked into using XmlAttributeOverrides?

[.NET Framework Class Library: XmlAttributeOverrides Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides.aspx)

> first, you can control and augment the serialization of objects found in a DLL--**even if you do not have access to the source**;
>
> second, you can create one set of serializable classes, but **serialize the objects in**
>   **multiple ways**. For example, instead of serializing members of a class
>   instance as XML elements, you can serialize them as XML attributes,
>   resulting in a more efficient document to transport.

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection to get the values of all the properties from the class then write them as attributes on to an XmlNode

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = control.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
  object o = property.GetValue(control, null);
  // write value of o.ToString() out as an attribute on a XmlNode
  // where attribute name is property.Name
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be almost the same as hand-coding, i.e. not using .NET XmlSerialization? 
The point is I just want to tinker a bit with the way the xml is created, applying different names and force the serializer to create attributes rather than elements for some properties.

Comment: There is some more information here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123540/modifying-existing-net-assembles, otherwise inheritance is your only option. My suggestion means that if an new attribute is added to the class you do not need to modify any code to serialize it.