# How can I programatically (using reflection?) change a method body and save my changes back to disk

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I can get at the method body easily enough using reflection

```
Type type = assembly.GetType("Lorem.Ipsum.Dolor.Sit");
MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("Amet");
MethodBody methodBody = methodInfo.GetMethodBody();
```

How can I programatically change the method body and save my changes back to disk?

Comment: Can you explain what the use of this would be? Why not just write a new method or extension method?

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to accomplish?  You can't change the method body with reflection alone.  MethodBody only gives you information about the MSIL inside (see doc <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbody.aspx>)

Comment: I will be given a path to an assembly, load it, remove all code from the method body (aside from what's needing to satisfy the return type), and save it as a new assembly to disk.

I believe that changing the method body will be less error prone than trying to use Assembly/Module/TypeBuilder and Reflection.Emit to try and duplicate the methods for a new, dynamically created assembly.

Don't bother asking "why do you want to do this", as I unfortunately can't share (NDA). :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't.

With reflection you modified an in-memory object which was produced from a binary loaded and optimized by the CLR at runtime.

**EDIT**

This question has some more information on this.

[Modifying Existing .NET Assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123540/modifying-existing-net-assemblies)

Comment: That link is very helpful and very similar to what I'm trying to accomplish.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

One another good lib for this:
https://bitbucket.org/0xd4d/dnlib

Handles obfuscated assemblies much better comparing to Mono.Cecil.

Answer (score 1):

you can't do it without third-party libs. take a look at: http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil